Extract HTML from current focused object in NVDA script
The title pretty much says it all. I want to write an NVDA script that extracts the HTML of the current focused object. Say I have the following script in my scratchpad directory (ie. %APPDATA%\nvda\scratchpad\globalPlugins\test.py).
import globalPluginHandler
from scriptHandler import script
import ui
import api
import scriptHandler

class GlobalPlugin(globalPluginHandler.GlobalPlugin):

    @script(gesture="kb:NVDA+shift+v")
    def script_announceNVDAVersion(self, gesture):
        f = api.getFocusObject()
        COPY_TO_CLIPBOARD(EXTRACT_HTML(f))

How would I implement the last line? Copying to the clipboard isn't really required, I just want a way to extract the HTML to save it somewhere.
